# Swfitmailer Scope in Function

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I've got a small function that implements use of `Swift_Mailer` to handle sending emails:

```
public function send(string $subject, $to, string $msg, $from = '')
{
    if (!empty($to)) {
        if (empty($from)) {
            $smtpSettings = $this->loadSettings();

            $from = [$smtpSettings['from_email'] => $smtpSettings['from_name']];
        }

        var_dump($to);

        $email = (new \Swift_Message($subject))
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setBody($msg);

        // Send the message
        $result = $this->swift->send($email);
    } else {
        var_dump('nein');
    }
}
```

Which gets used here:

```
$mailer->send(
    'Some Subject',
    [$email],
    'Hello, world'
);
```

This returns this message:

> 0: Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

After a quick Googles, it seems the `Swift_Message` instance isn't getting the `$to` value properly.

I added the `var_dump($to)` to the script to see what's actually in it, and I get:

```
array(1) {
  string(19) "someemail@domain.com"
}
```

The email above is psuedo for my real email, which I copy/pasted into thunderbird and sent an email to - all good, so I know the email is valid.

However, the error message seems to show that no email was passed. My code more or less mirrors the [documentation](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html) but for some reason, my email isn't getting passed.

Does `Swift_Message` have some weird scope issues? It doesn't seem like `$subject` or `$from` are going wrong, so why is the `$to` potentially not in-scope?

Comment: Maybe the address you don't show _does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2_?  Also, what is `$from`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver possibly, is a standard gmail account though, nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: @AbraCadaver `$from` = another gmail account I set up for SMTP usage

Comment: @AbraCadaver you were right about the $from format, I copied the code from documentation, and used that - it worked, changed variables one by one, broke with `$from` - not `$to`. Just gave a red herring message :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AbraCadaver led me towards the right path, more so than the error message returned to me.

I copied the original code from the [documentation](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html) and replaced the values one-by-one with the corresponding `$var`, all worked, even `$to` - the message was a red herring.

The `$from` variable however, is what broke the script. The value was incorrectly formatted, fixing the format fixed the script.

I set `$from` to `['theemail@domain.com' => 'Some Name']` and all was well.